# Where is the `parent` variable that points to Window object in Chrome defined?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I just incidentally forgot to remove `console.log(parent)` in my experiment and it logged `Window`. I didn't know there's the global variable `parent`. Where is it defined? I'm using latest Chrome.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's defined in [the HTML specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-window-object), specifically [here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-parent):

> The parent IDL attribute, on getting, must run the following algorithm:
>
> 1. Let *windowProxy* be this Window object's [`WindowProxy`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#windowproxy) object.
> 2. If there is no [browsing context](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#browsing-context) with *windowProxy* as its `WindowProxy` object, then return null.
> 3. Let *context* be that [browsing context](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#browsing-context).
> 4. If *context* is a [child browsing context](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#child-browsing-context) of another browsing context *parent*, then return *parent*'s `WindowProxy` object.
> 5. Otherwise, *context* must be a [top-level browsing context](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#top-level-browsing-context). Return *context*'s `WindowProxy` object.

See also [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/parent).

Basically, `parent` is the window's parent (e.g., it's a frame or iframe), if it has one, or the window itself if it doesn't.

There's also the related, but different, `opener` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener) | [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-opener)).

Comment: cool, thanks! it's interesting I never saw it mentioned in the books I read